# Select WiFi Access point in Android?

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing one android application which select wifi access point from list of wifi. I used following code..

```
 WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration(); 
wifiConfiguration.SSID = hotSpotSsid; 
wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE); 
wifiConfiguration.BSSID = hotSpotBssid; 
wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false;
```

// wifiConfiguration.priority = 1;

```
// add this to the configured networks 
int inetId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration); 
Log.i(TAG,"INetId :"+inetId); 
configs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
Log.e(TAG,"After adding config :"+configs); 
if(inetId < 0) { 
    Log.i(TAG,"Unable to add network configuration for SSID: "+hotSpotSsid); 
    return; 
}else { 
    message="\t Successfully added to configured Networks"; 
    Log.i(TAG,message); 
}
```

My problem is i am not able select wifi access point..Every time it shows previous configured wifi details.

Comment: you could always check the source code for the settings app http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to call [WifiManager.enableNetwork](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) with disableOthers=true

```
wifiManager.enableNetwork(inetId, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include permissions given below in your manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```