# Can an application programaticallyrequest that a particular WIFI network be connected to?

Tags: android, wifi

How can one programatically set an app to connect to a particular WIFI network?  Thanks  That is disconnect if its currently connected to another wifi and then connected to a wifi name contained say in a shared preferences.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select WiFi Access point in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173304/select-wifi-access-point-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

use disableNetwork() method of WifiManager class.

thanks.